# how to select all results from a column in database

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have a form with a select field:

```
<select class="indexSearchLocationList" name="locationList">
    <option value="allLocations">Anywhere in London</option>
    <option value="barking_and_dagenham">Barking and Dagenham </option>
    <option value="barnet">Barnet</option>
```

What im trying to do is if the user chooses the option allocations (Anywhere in London) then I need to use that to select all when querying the database below is the php I currently have but how do I specifiy if that particular option is choosen:

```
$choosenLocation = $_POST['locationList'];
```

Comment: Show the code were you construct the database query.

Comment: I highly suggest you use stored procedures, not sending a query like all the answers have posted, otherwise you leave yourself wide open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this, if it is not meet your requirement, then add your requirement briefly as comment.

```
$choosenLocation = $_POST['locationList'];

    if($choosenLocation == 'allLocations')
    {

       $query = "select * from TABLE ";


    }
    else
    {
       $query = "select * from TABLE WHERE condition="any_condition";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect something similar,

```
        $choosenLocation = $_POST['locationList'];

        if(isset($choosenLocation) && $choosenLocation == 'allLocations'){

           $query = "select * from TABLE ";

           //based on the mysqli_ or PDO you execute

           //fetch the row and display accordingly

        }else{

             $query = "select * from TABLE WHERE condition='your condition here' " ;
          }
```

Comment: any change i can get a up vote as i can no longer post questions

Answer (score 0):

I think  that may be

```
    if(isset($_POST['locationList']) & $_POST['locationList']=='allLocations')
   {

       $query = "select * from TABLE ";

       //based on the mysqli_ or PDO you execute

       //fetch the row and display accordingly

    }
```